# Error on fetching list of GoogleSheets using Google Drive Api

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api to fetch all google sheets from the drive

Currently it is giving me 403 error back
I have enabled google drive api in developer console

In developer console dashboard, drive api is still showing 0 requests whereas other api request counts are greater than 100

Atleast no. of errors should be shown in dashboard right?
In the case of drive api nothing is being shown.
What could be the reason?

```
 let sheets = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false",
      headers: `Bearer ${token}`
    });
```

This is the code

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: It appears you are wrapping the quotes of your query too short. And I don't know if you require URL encoding the query string